# Add Media to Answer's 'Footnotes' Local Repo or Link?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, repository

Programming is language, so answers on this SE should always include language no matter what.  But for those who struggle with English as a second language, who aren't good with words, and for those who learn and/or teach better through action, examples and experience: what do you think of adding the possibility [earned with rep-points] of linking to a repository [on the SE network, or on legitimate sites] with example projects, source code, etc.

Some questions are just hard to explain, period, or succinctly—even for some code and literary geniuses.  Including code and offering a demonstration of the question asked—especially examples that could be tailored by and for anyone—would be priceless.

Of course I see how this could be possibly be a nightmare to moderate, but if well thought-out and executed, it could elevate Stack Exchange out of the Q&A obscurity and truly become the Wiki the project aims to be.

Answer (score 1):

To be useful as a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) I think you will need to flesh out your proposal a lot more because the Devil is in the detail.

Some parts of this are already in place like [Stack Snippets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?cb=1) or works in progress like [Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow).

Personally, I think Stack Exchange emerged out of Q&A obscurity long ago.